# Database opening and closing advice

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am developing a simple database project. It has some functions that will be performed on database. I need advice about opening and closing database. Which way is the better below?

When program starts, open database and close when program finishes.

When program starts, when a function is called, open database, and at the end of this function close database.

I am confused for which one is better. In the first case database will be open during the program. In the second case database opening and closing operation will be performed at each function call and also for each function. This will reduce efficiency and also makes code longer.

So which one is the better?

Comment: Research a little about ORMs. I would recommend Hibernate http://www.hibernate.org/

Answer (score 1):

Better is subjective.  If you have only a few clients connecting to the database, for short periods of time then perhaps leaving a connection open is the better way to go.  However, if you have hundreds of clients needing connections, there are limited number of simultaneous connections that can be supported, keeping the connection open for long periods would be detrimental.

There is an overhead involved in opening and closing connections to the database but you have to balance that against whether the language actually pools the connections for you so it only appears that the connection is closed but if needed will be reused and if not really closed after some period of time, and many other possible criteria.

Better is what meets your needs in the simplest to maintain manner.

Comment: To add to the above answer.  I've found it best not to deal with connection handling unless I absolutely have to. Spring's JdbcTemplate can save you a lot of coding and issues in regards to dealing with connections and also provide an easy way to swap out the implementation of the underlying data source that handles the connection.  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate

Comment: Opening a connection is expensive. Sharing some open connections is usually the way to go. To give an idea of relative costs, some old measurements for a simple query on Oracle: 500ms to establish a connection, 75ms to prepare statement, 10ms to execute query. But as said in the other responses, the driver could do pooling for you transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate function like `getConnection()` which will create and return a `Connection` object. Put all your code that will create the connection there.

now if in any function you need a database connection call `getConnection()`

```
public void myfunction()
{
    javax.sql.Connection con = MyConnectionClass.getConnection();
    con.open();

    // do your business logic here

    con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very little cost to leaving a connection open longer than necessary, so that would favor your idea to open when the program starts and close upon exiting the program.